# Subquery checking for next elements

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am currently working on a Database-Security-System, have to make sure that in the next two minutes of this database there is no other entry that equals to true. But somehow I always end up getting a System.NotSupportedException.

#### My Code

```cs
public IQueryable<AuthorizationAttempt> GetSuspiciousActivity(
    DateTime from, 
    DateTime to)
{
    return GetActivity(from, to).Where(e1 => 
        e1.Result == false 
        && !GetActivity(
                e1.AttemptDate,
                e1.AttemptDate.AddMinutes(2d)
            ).Any(e2 => e2.Result == true));
}
```

#### Error

System.NotSupportedException: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMinutes(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the return type of `GetActivity`?

Comment: i think ``GetActivity`` return by default ``null`` not empty list.

Comment: Need more deatils about the exception. GetActivity is a DbContext class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any helper methods inside your LINQ query. Use DbFunctions instead.